# ESP8266 Arduino IDE JSON HTTP REQUEST

Tags: json, wifi, arduino-esp8266

I've been trying to get weather information on my ESP8266 to display them on an OLED Display.

```
if (!client.connect("api.apixu.com", 80)) {
  Serial.println("connection failed");
   return;}

  client.print("GET " + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
  "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" + 
  "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

   char c[1024];
  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
   while(client.available()){
      c[0] = client.read();Serial.print(c);}
```

That's my code for requesting and reading the JSON content. But whatever I try, the code won't enter the while loop.

Can someone spot the mistake?

Thank you in advance! :D

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it somehow this code works for everyone who had the same error that `available()` was always 0.

```c++
client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
```